# Insert name of clicked button into database

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to insert name/id of clicked button into database.

```
<button id="test" class="button button-light" data-ng-click="showAlert($event)">Click Me</button>
```

I am getting id ( test ) of button and showing it as alert

```
$scope.showAlert = function(event){
    alert(event.target.id);
}
```

Getting id works fine. But is it possible to send id/name of button to database field?

How can I put this id into this function ( at this moment I have only username from input field and it works fine)

```
$scope.addnew = function(filename) {
        $http.post('addtodb.php',{'username' : $scope.username}
        ).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        });
    }
```

Comment: How are these 2 functions related? Just add 2 more properties to your data that you're sending.

Comment: I take data username from input field like this: <input ng-model="username" type="number" class="validate"> is it possible to use ng-model on button? When I click on button then it send into database value from ng-model?

Comment: Have you tried adding another argument to `$scope.addnew` for the `id`, adding `id` to the `POST` object, and calling your `$scope.addnew` function from within `$scope.showAlert`?

Comment: doesn't work...